Copy cookies across micro services or its alternative
I had been a system programmer. I am new to web or micro services programming and docker environment. All my services are exposed to the same network.
I have a keycloak server, that provides authentication. I have a UI micro server, that shall work with a couple of servers at the backend. The Keycloak server and the UI server's are exposed, through traefik.
All my backend servers also authenticate with keycloak. When a browser authenticates with keycloak, the browser receives some tokens, and those get carried to the UI server. Now UI needs to work with the backend server's but I am unaware of how to pass these tokens to the backend servers, for them to validate the user and their role.
Any help on how to achieve this would be very helpful.
I tried multiple options like using nextauth or using cookie copy. May be I am doing something wrong there.
